# Is there any way in Apache to specify a single .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My hosting allows use of .htaccess files as the configuration files are not available.

I'm aware of the performance hit that override files incur though - so I was thinking - If Apache provided a mode for having a single .htaccess file - wouldn't that be faster than having to check for multiple .htaccess files whilst still maintaining the convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If Apache provided a mode for having a single `.htaccess` file

Well, not a "mode" as such, but you could achieve this by allowing `.htaccess` for the parent directory (root directory or even one above the document root) and disable the use of `.htaccess` files in all subdirectories. The `.htaccess` file in the parent directory will still apply.

Realistically (if indeed this is at all "realistic"), you would probably need to enable `.htaccess` for the directory "above the document root" and disable `.htaccess` in the document root and below, rather than enabling `.htaccess` for the document root. Otherwise, if you enable `.htaccess` for the document root, you will have to disable `.htaccess` for each subdirectory individually. And if you add more subdirectories, the server config will need to be updated accordingly. (Since, the `AllowOverride` directive is only allowed in `<Directory>` containers *without regex*, not `<DirectoryMatch>` containers.) However, this might not be possible on some shared hosting environments (there might not be an "above the document root") and it could impact the installation of some CMSs.

Note that you obviously need access to the server config (or VirtualHost) in order to implement this, so it is hypothetical in this instance.

> wouldn't that be faster than having to check for multiple .htaccess files

Possibly. But you are only talking about a micro-optimsation at best in real terms. On most sites, even enabling `.htaccess` files at all will hardly be noticeable - if at all. The "performance hit" you speak of is not as big as you might think. To put it another way, if you are finding that `.htaccess` is proving to be a bottle neck then you've either done something wrong, or you have far more serious problems to address.

Note, however, that you are generally only using `.htaccess` files on smaller sites anyway. On larger / high traffic sites you will have your own VPS / Server and access to the server config, so there wouldn't be any need to use `.htaccess` (or, importantly, have it enabled).

> whilst still maintaining the convenience?

Not exactly. Part of the "convenience" is being able to put the `.htaccess` file in any directory you like, overriding parent directives and have it apply to just that directory tree. (It is the *userland* equivalent of the `<Directory>` container in the server config.)

Comment: You're welcome. I just added another paragraph about "implementation"... using `.htaccess` in the directory "above the document root", rather than the document root.